# Error while building project : app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, jvm

My project is multimodule.

When I'm building the project i'm having this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform ddmlib-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.3.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Zakhar\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.ddms\ddmlib\30.3.0\f271cb990dc62f580b608a75c87c509683c75da9\ddmlib-30.3.0.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
           Increase the minSdkVersion to 26 or above.

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'google/protobuf/field_mask.proto' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\Zakhar\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.protobuf\protobuf-javalite\3.21.7\82b692be08383107fd1c6d44474b56df411edd27\protobuf-javalite-3.21.7.jar
      - C:\Users\Zakhar\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.protobuf\protobuf-java\3.17.2\d7eec2ad499b605f24d07f49bdcb41c801aafbfc\protobuf-java-3.17.2.jar
     Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
     https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
     for more information

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.17.2) and protobuf-javalite-3.21.7 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.21.7)
     Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-java-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.17.2) and protobuf-javalite-3.21.7 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.21.7)
```

---

I was trying to change libraries versions, agp, build.gradle plugin.

Here is my code from each build.gradle.kts modules:

app:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.nutrition.caloriecountingapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.nutrition.caloriecountingapp"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    viewBinding.isEnabled = true


}

val daggerVersion = "2.48"
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:22.5.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    implementation(project(":feature_auth"))
    implementation(project(":feature_home"))
    implementation(project(":feature_search"))
    implementation(project(":feature_profile"))
    implementation(project(":core"))
    implementation(project(":db"))
    implementation(project(":network"))

    implementation("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")

    // Dagger
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion")
    ksp ("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion")
}
```

---

:core

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.nutrition.core"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    viewBinding.isEnabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

:db

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.test.db"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
        kotlin{
           ksp{
               arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
           }
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    // Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")

    // Dagger
    val daggerVersion = "2.48"
    compileOnly("com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion")
    ksp ("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion")
}
```

:feature_auth

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.nutrition.feature_auth"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    viewBinding.isEnabled = true
}


dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2")

    // core
    implementation(project(":core"))

    // db
    implementation(project(":db"))

    // Navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5")

    // Lifecycle
    val lifecycleVersion = "2.6.2"
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")

    // Testing
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.5")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.7.3")

    // Dagger
    val daggerVersion = "2.48"
    compileOnly("com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion")
    ksp ("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion")

    // Firebase
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.9.1")

    // WorkManager
    val workManagerVersion = "2.9.0"
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime:$workManagerVersion")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$workManagerVersion")
    
    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")

}
```

---

:feature_home

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.nutrition.feature_home"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    viewBinding.isEnabled = true
}



dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    // Dagger
    val daggerVersion = "2.48"
    compileOnly("com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion")
    
    implementation(project(":core"))
    implementation(project(":db"))

    // Glide
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")


}
```

:feature_profile

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.test.feature_profile"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    viewBinding.isEnabled = true
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

:feature_search

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.nutrition.feature_search"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    viewBinding.isEnabled = true
}



dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    // Dagger
    val daggerVersion = "2.48"
    compileOnly("com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion")

    implementation(project(":core"))

}
```

---

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.test.network"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

---

```
// gradle.properties
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

Hope, that your answer will help to fix that problem.

Comment: Have you tried invalidate cache and sync your project again?

Comment: @HosseinShahmohammadi already try, but that didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

In your error there is this hint :
Increase the minSdkVersion to 26 or above.

Have you changed minSDKVersion?